# Why should one create List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

I have seen it in some frameworks and tools when there is a generic `List<Object>`. What is the point of creating `List` that's type is `Object`? Is it obsolete or is there a reason behind it?

**EDIT**
Yes, IDE might display warning, but you can add `SuppressWarning`, because in my opinion it is misleading when you use generics for `Object` type

Comment: There are cases where it makes sense, there are cases where it doesnt.

Comment: Well I am curious about the cases when it makes sense

Comment: It makes sense when you want a list of objects. There's hardly more behind this (except the possible corner case that micha mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters are not optional: `List` is a fundamentally different type than `List<Object>`.

The only reason raw types exist in Java is legacy code. You should never write code which introduces a new occurrence of a raw type.

One important case where the difference between `List` and `List<Object>` becomes crucial would be the following:

```
static void addObject(List<Object> objs) { objs.add("a"); }

static void addObjectToRaw(List objs) { objs.add("a"); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Boolean> bools = new ArrayList<>();
   addObject(bools);       // compiler detects error
   addObjectToRaw(bools);  // compiler is silent
}
```

Accepting a raw `List` as an argument has the effect of removing all type safety.

Comment: I agree with you, but the only reason to type <Object> here is to avoid warning and follow convention that raw types shouldn't be used at all?

Comment: @RooMan I would be very confused, if I see non-generic `List`, it will just make me thinking, why is it here, but when I see `List<Object>`, I understand, why is it written so.

Comment: I agree with you on using raw types. I just thought there was some deeper meaning to it.

Comment: @RooMan: I'm quite sure there are cases where you actually break type inference with a raw type. If I find one, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some IDEs and code checkers show warnings if you use generic classes without specifying a generic type parameter (e.g. `List l`).

By adding `<Object>` you indicate that this list is meant to store objects and that you not just forget to add a generic type parameter.

It is also helpfull if you have to work with older (pre Java 1.5) code that didn't support 
generics. If you see a `List l` in such a situation, you can never be sure if it is old code (written before generics exist) or if the collections actually stores items of type `Object`.

Comment: I'm from C# world and there List<T> have more efficient implementation rather than ArrayList which was deprecated by fact. May be Java has same logic. An one of approach i see is to unify collections to have one List<T> instead of ArrayList, CoolList, BestList and so on.

Answer (score -1):

The point of doing this is actually that you can store any Object in it.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects.add(1);
objects.add("Toto");
objects.add(12.2f);
for(Object o : objects){
  System.out.println(o);
}
```

will print :
1 
Toto
12.2

That's the difference

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();Now, let's try the code below:

list1.add("");// this works fine
list2.add("");// this one issues a compile error
```

Comment: What is the difference from option if you don't use generic <Object>?